# Issues with Selenium Click on Link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a strange issue with Python Selenium when trying to click on the next page link in Curry's PC World Televisions page. See the next button on (https://www.currys.co.uk/tv-and-audio/televisions/tvs)

I am testing in non-headless mode with chrome, so i can see the outline of the next button being highlighted, when actioning the click, but it is not navigating to the next page url as expected.

Here is what i have tried on the page above:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.currys.co.uk/tv-and-audio/televisions/tvs')

next_page_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                 ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
                                            'ul.pagination '
                                            'li.pagination-arrrow-next a.page-next')))
next_page_link.click()

time.sleep(10)
```

I have also tried using execute script, (which does not work either):

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_page_link)
```

I am able to extract the href from the link element (so i know its the right element):

```
href = next_page_link.get_attribute('href')
print("href is: {}".format(href))
# href is: https://www.currys.co.uk/tv-and-audio/televisions/tvs?start=20&sz=20
```

I'm a bit lost as to what the issue might be here, would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

I see the following issues here:

1. You have to close the accept cookies pop-up.
2. You need to scroll the page down to the pager elements.
3. Selenium indeed doesn't make the page to go to the next page **BUT** even when I click the `Next` button manually or even any other pagination button there manually the page is not changed. So, the problem is with the web page itself, not with Selenium.
   This is the code I used:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.currys.co.uk/tv-and-audio/televisions/tvs'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
next_page_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul.pagination li.pagination-arrrow-next a.page-next')))
next_page_link.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
next_page_link.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested by putting in a delay at the end so I could click the pagination buttons manually and i opened the console on chrome. When clicking the pagination button it makes a request to api endpoint using an ajax call to update the products on that page, but i can see that the server responds with 403 (forbidden) each time. So it seems they know I am a bot somehow...

Comment: That also possible...